# Wrapping default windows thumbnail handler for photos

Tags: windows, thumbnails, windows-shell

I would like to write a new thumbnail handler for photos. I want my thumbnail handler to be activated only on some specific folders. If the file is not in on of these special folders, I simply would like to forward the call to windows default thumbnail handler. So I want my thumbnail handler to be a simple wrapper over the default one.
Is there a way to call the default handler from my handler code?

If it matters, this is relevant only for windows 10.

Thanks,